# How to list contacts belonging to an iOS group using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, contacts

I have found the following code in Apple developer documentation however I cannot understand how to correctly call this function. Would really appreciate any guidance.

```
func fetchContactsInGroup(with identifier: String, completion: @escaping (_ contacts: [CNContact]) -> Void) {
    var result = [CNContact]()
    // Fetch only the full name of a person or organization.
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])

    // Predicate to fetch all contacts that are members of the specified group.
    request.predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier: identifier)

    contactStoreQueue.async {
        do {
            try self.store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: {(contact, status) -> Void in
                // Add each retured contact to result.
                result.append(contact)
            })
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part exactly don't you get?

Comment: the syntax for calling func fetchContactsInGroup - the completion: bit is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems from comments, that your problem is with blocks. The simplest way to call this method is like this :

```
fetchContactsInGroup(with: "groupName") { (retrievedContacts:[CNContact]) in
    // your code to proccess retrievedContacts goes here
}
```

Now, to explain a bit : this `completion` parameter is a closure - simply put its a block of code stored in a variable. It's a fairly common pattern in iOS SDK, so I encourage you to learn about it. This block is passed, because the method itself retrieves the contacts asynchronously. When it finishes, the passed block of code will be called. It is important to keep in mind that this can happen anytime in the future. If the contacts were retrieved synchronously on the main thread, you'd get an impression that your app hanged which is bad.
This is a very simple explanation, [here is a documentation about closures in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). I highly encourage you to read it thoroughly, and other online tutorials about it online. If you haven't used closures/lambdas before it may not be straightforward to grasp, but you really should get accustomed to it.

Comment: It worked fine with [CNContact] however I needed to change to a type I have defined  and get this error
/Users/jeremyandrews/Documents/swift/ARUA Swift 3/ARUA/ControlRoom/ControlRoom/Contacts.swift:72:58: Cannot convert value of type '(([ContactEntry]?) -> Void).Type' (aka \'((Optional<Array<ContactEntry>>) -> ()).Type') to expected argument type '([ContactEntry]?) -> Void'
There is something I am obviously missing.
Would appreciate any guidance

Comment: Well, that's because you usually cannot convert between two arbitrary types. You retrieve the contacts from the system, and the system knows nothing about your class. You need to convert it manually from `CNContact` to `ContactEntry` in the completion block.